# Image In Div With Max Width Not Working

Tags: html, css, image

I'm applying `max-width` to a div containing an image, but the image ignores the applied value.

Screenshot:

[image: Image overlapping]

Snippet:

```css
.screenshot {
      max-width: 460px;
      margin: 27px;
    }
    
    .description {
      max-width: 705px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="screenshot">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/850x850" alt="App">
    </div>
    <div class="description">text you see in screenshot.
    </div>
```

Comment: Please consider up voting this.

Comment: 1000+ views and 1 up vote. Nice job, SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max-width would have to be on the image.

Image elements don't care what dimensions their parent tells them--they will simply stretch the parent container to fit anyways.

Edit: for example, you can create a new rule whose selector is *.screenshot img* and then apply the max-width there.

**Edit** If you try this rule with ids it won't work, it only works with classes.

Comment: the img is in a div with the class called on it. Shouldn't that work?

Comment: The div is the parent container for the img. Putting the max-width property on the parent will not descend to the img. The max-width property must be on the img. You can instead create a rule that targets the img and apply the max-width property.

Comment: I moved class="screenshot" in the img tag, and it worked. Are you saying the only alternative would be to change the css to **img** {max..} instead of  **screenshot** {..} ?

Comment: What would I actually be doing if I wrote *.screenshot img*?

Comment: You could put the screenshot class in the image too. For example, <img src="whatever" alt="you should consider accessibility" class="screenshot" />. Then you could have a selector that just said .screenshot and it would work. The .screenshot img selector is a descendant selector, meaning that any image that descends from an element that invokes the class screenshot will be targeted.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options you can try

Try using div.screenshot{ max-width:460px } to strengthen your target selection

Try using an id tag instead of a div, as id tags get more priority

Try adding !important in your div i.e .screenshot{ max-width:460px !important }